# How to convert function call with two callbacks to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have a function like this:

```
var f = function(options, successCallback, errorCallback) {
   ...
}
```

and I want to convert it's call to a promise. My current solution is this:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();

f(options,
    function (result) {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    }, function (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    }
);

return deferred.promise;
```

I can't use the Q.fcall because it expects a Node.js-style callback `function(err, result) { ... }`

So, is there a way to improve my code using the [Q API](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all these helper functions (based on [`Deferred.makeNodeResolver`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#deferredmakenoderesolver)) are only there to deal with the ugly nodebacks. If the callback-style method already takes separate success and error callbacks not much extra work needs to be done.

You could simplify your pattern by removing those unnecessary closure function expressions:

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
f(options, deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
return deferred.promise;
```

You could also use the [`Promise` constructor](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qpromiseresolver), which is the preferred method for promise creation (bonus: catches exceptions `throw`n by `f`):

```
return new Q.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    f(options, resolve, reject);
});
```

which might even be shortened with partial application to

```
return new Q.Promise(f.bind(null, options));
```

---

See also the generic reference: [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)